# Dealing with Root objects in the result of a Fourier transform of a complex impedance

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a complex impedance which I want to back transform into the time domain. My attempt in MM is:

```
InverseFourierTransform[1/((I \[Omega] Cs)/(1 - Cs Ls \[Omega]^2) + 1/Rp + I \[Omega] Cp + 1/(I \[Omega] Lp)), \[Omega], t, Assumptions->Cp > 0 && Lp > 0 && Cs > 0 && Ls > 0 && Rp > 0]
```

However this spits out some nasty expressions expressions with `Root[...]` arguments, but given how nasty the current output is, or, I'm not sure how to deal with the output.

The objective is I want to weight the 'time-transient impedance' and then then Fourier transform it back into the frequency domain to see what my weighting does.

Comment: You can use `ToRadicals` to get more familiar notation, but the result is far uglier. Symbolic expressions for temporal behavior of coupled resonators are generally extremely complicated. That's just mathematics: there is no cure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

There something wrong below (...~p~... should be replace simply by ...+... ?). I will see that later

**END EDIT**

**EDIT 2**

I'm entering difficulties : once my error corrected, I have the root objects. (Nothing glorious in fact.)

**END EDIT 2**

Apparently you are calculating the transient response of this :

[image: schematic]

Here is how I would do it :

```
x_ ~p~ y_ := x y /(x + y) (* definition of a "parallel operator on impedances *)  

ti00 = (1/(Lp s)) ~p~ (Cp s) ~p~ (Rp)~p~ (1/(1/(Ls s) + (Cs s))) // 
   Expand // Together (* this is the circuit above *)  

tf = TransferFunctionModel[{{ti00}}, s]  

OutputResponse[tf, UnitStep[t], t] (* litteral output response *)  

 (* example of numeric output response to a unit step (not a dirac) : *)
outR00 = OutputResponse[
   tf /. {Lp -> 1, Cp -> 1, Rp -> 1, Ls -> 1, Cs -> 1}, 
   UnitStep[t], {t, 0, 10}]  

Plot[outR00 , {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Note : The stimulus is a voltage step. The response is a the current.

Comment: The schematic was created with a tool used on ElectricalEngineering Stack Exchange. (Very convenient)

Comment: This is absolutely glorious.

Comment: One final question, once I weight my data, I actually want to apply a Hanning window, how would one transform back into the frequency domain?

Comment: I don't know exactly and I don't want to run the risk to mislead the readers.

Comment: Okay, maybe I will ask on the EESE -- Thanks!!

Comment: @andre314 Please could you give a link for the tool used to draw the schematic? Thanks

Comment: @Hugh I can't find a link. What I have done : I have started to ask a fake question on ElectricalEngineering Stack Exchange, then I have clicked on the icon "schematic",  just after the icon "import image", then I made the drawing, then click on "save and insert" to import the html in the question, and finally copy-paste the html in a MSE question. Hope I'm clear, otherwise ask ...